# Override jQuery cycle via <a> link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to access the jQuery cycle via a link to override the i variable?

I've seen examples that do this, but not in a case like this where cycle() function is inside a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();
});

$(window).load(function() {

    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
        i = 0;

    (function cycle() {

        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
                  .delay(5000)
                  .fadeOut(400, cycle);

        if (typeof window["Stage" + i] != 'undefined')
        {
            window["Stage" + i].destroy();
        }

        i = ++i % divs.length; // increment i, 
                               // and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
        if (i == 1)
        {
            window["Stage" + i] = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('graph_lines'), swiffyobject);
        }
        else if (i === 0)
        {
            window["Stage" + i] = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('circle_lines'), circleobject);
        }

        window["Stage" + i].start();

    })();

});
```

[Demo Link](http://beta.suissamesser.com/demo2.html)

Comment: why do you use jQuery DOM ready event **and** `window.load`? I think you have to learn a bit about jQuery... No offence but your code implies it rather clearly.

Comment: Thx. It's just leftover. Earlier I had code that accessed swiffy via a static variable and it had to wait for swiffy to load first otherwise it was coming up undefined. No need for it now. Need to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Next time, take the time to format the code so it's at least a bit more readable. Don't expect people to put the effort of answering your question if you don't put the effort to write your question properly. Formatting included.

Comment: Sorry...honest mistake and I'm pretty new with jQuery, just didn't realize it was there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking whether cycle can be globally accessed, then the short answer is

### No

Your `cycle` function is part of a private function closure. You'll have to make it global for it to work that way. But it's highly recommended that we don't pollute global scope so you should apply this function to your links within that closure:

```
$(function(){
    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();

    var cycle = function() {
        // do the thing although you're using globals etc.
    }

    $("a").click(cycle);
});
```

Anyway this is the way to do this, but you will have to clean up your code removing globals unless they're **really** needed. And learn about jQuery and how it works and don't do same things twice. When you'll learn a little you'll know what I'm talking about.

> **Note**: I'm not sure what you mean by *override* via `a` link. I've attached to it to click event in my example, but that may not be what you want. You'll have to be much more specific.

### Running swiffy on link click

I suggest you make your life easy on yourself and add links like:

```
<a href="#" class="start-swiffy" data-swiffy="0">Start swiffy 0</a>
```

And have this code instead:

```
$(function() {
    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();

    divs.each(function(index) {
        $(this).fadeIn(400)
               .delay(5000)
               .fadeOut(400);

        // replaces first if statement
        window["Stage" + index] && window["Stage" + index].destroy();

        if (index === 0)
        {
            window["Stage1"] = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('graph_lines'), swiffyobject);
        }

        if (index === divs.length - 1)
        {
            window["Stage0"] = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('circle_lines'), circleobject);
        }

        window["Stage" + ((index + 1) % divs.length)].start();
    });

    $("a.start-swiffy").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        window["Stage" + $(this).data("swiffy")].start();
    });
});
```

Even though I still don't understand why do you do all those `div` fades and removing stages and running them in offset sequence by one so they start from the second and the first one starts last? That is the main part that could be improved I guess...

Comment: Thank you very much, this all makes a lot of sense. To clarify, this code is in a linked js file. What I want to do is have numbered links on the HTML page that can force the cycle function to start a specific animation. So while it's cycling through all of these animation the user could just click 3 and that one is initiated.

Comment: @jsuissa: What would you like to execute on link click? fadeIn/delay/fadeOut or would you like to start swiffies? Because running cycle would go through all `n to divs.length` where `n` is the index of your link you clicked... And you said you just want one animation to be executed...

Comment: What I'm looking to do is change the div and in turn run the animation associated with it. The equivalent of `cycle(n)` even though I can't do that as is. This [demo](http://beta.suissamesser.com/demo2.html) shows the idea, the buttons on the upper right would each be associated with 1 of 4 stories (only 2 exist now).

Comment: @jsuissa: Looking at your demo page: why don't you then just simply use one of the gazillion carousel jQuery plugins then? They're reliable and some provide exactly what you need.

Comment: Thx for all the help on this. Found plenty that can rotate between divs or images. I haven't found any that look like they'd work in this case where both the div has to rotate and the swiffy instance has to be started. Is there one in particular you had in mind?

Comment: @jsuissa: many of these carousels provide different additional functionality. I'm sure many provide an event hook when a switch happens. So in that handler you should be able to start your swiffy. I've also created a super simplified example with a little bit of code (lots of it is plumbing to get demo working), that does auto cyclic carousel. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/azj4T/). You can as well start your swiffy in the `switcher` function. Just in case you still want to have your own code. :)